# Nuxt.js routing

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am migrating from ASP.NET MVC to Nuxt.js and I am trying to keep the same urls so I can keep the SEO ratings

My current URLs are

[www.url.com/#computers/#laptops/#dell?page=1](http://www.url.com/#computers/#laptops/#dell?page=1)

All of the # are dynamic values so URL might also be

[www.url.com/#phones/#smartphones/#apple?page=1](http://www.url.com/#phones/#smartphones/#apple?page=1)

What is the easiest way to point all these URLs to one page ITEMS and to be able to get values for every # and also for QueryString values ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `serverMiddleware` in nuxt

Make a file for your middleware:

`middleware/server/seoMiddleware.js`

Add that to your `nuxt.config.js` in the `serverMiddleware` block:

```
serverMiddleware: [
  '~/middleware/server/seoMiddleware.js'
]
```

Create a file to handle a list of your 301's:

`middleware/server/301.js`

Add your path mapping using regex in your `301.js`:

```
export default [
    { from: '/(#[\w\d]+)\/(#[\w\d]+)\/(#[\w\d]+)', to: 'items', capture: true }
]
```

Pop open your `seoMiddleware`.js

```
const redirects = require('./301.js').default

export default function (req, res, next) {
  const redirect = redirects.find(redirect => req.url.test(redirect.from))

  if (redirect) {
    const to = redirect.capture ? applyCapturesToUrl(req.url, redirect) : redirect.to

    res.writeHead(301, { Location: to })
    res.end()
  }
  
  // failover
  next()
}

const applyCapturesToUrl(url, redirect) {
  const matches = url.match(redirect.from)

  return `/${redirect.to}/` + matches.map(match => match.replace('#', '')).join('/')
}
```

We've used some simple regex here to create capture groups based on your URL structure and and serverMiddleware to intercept the request and return a `301` (permanent redirect) if we find a match. We failover with `next()` and allow the request through if there was no match found. We use a `capture` flag on the redirect object so we know when we're dealing with capture groups, without it we can just do simple pattern matching.